# Problems using assets with symfony

Tags: php, css, symfony, composer-php, assets

I have created a new project and I want to integrate a css sheet within my website

to add the css files I have done it as follows

[line code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEfn6.png)

and first of all I used the following commands

***composer require symfony/webpack-encore-bundle***

tells me to use one of the following commands

***npm install***

or

***yarn install***

but I have the following errors

[npm install error 1 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnDCg.png)

[yarn install error 2 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTXtE.png)

Comment: Please share more details, like the error message in text form and your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: Consider adding the code as text instead of pictures.

Answer (score -1):

You should install node and yarn in your laptop

https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-18.04/

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: Is it necessary in windows?